# How to select and fetch from a comma saperated value mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a value

```
$id=10,12,4,45; //these are ids of all the products in product table
```

Now I want to show (echo) products' names which are given in this single variable.

Something like:

```
query="SELECT description from product where id ='$id' ";
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Topic to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @u_mulder I think (and I hope) this isn't stored in DB, this is the content of a php variable

Comment: `$query="SELECT description from product where id in ('$id') ";`

Comment: no i have saved it in DB by implode() function

Comment: You should normalize your database.

Comment: okay i try to normalize

Answer (score 3):

Use `find_in_Set()`

```
SELECT description from product where find_in_set(id,'$id')
```